# Read cookie in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, rest, cookies

in a wpf application I have to call an external rest service which returns a cookie with session id in it. In all subsequent calls I have to send session id in cookie otherwise it does not return any data.

So how can I retrieve the cookie in wpf code behind class?

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var domain = EndPoint;
HttpResponseMessage response2 = client.PostAsync(domain, new StringContent(parameters)).Result;

Uri uri = new Uri(domain);
IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
var cookieWithId = responseCookies.Single(o => o.Name == "JESSSIONID");
```

where EndPoint has http://mydomain.com:38080/workshop/ and parameters has rest/login?username=usr&password=pwd

Comment: Check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190806/Send-Cookies-When-Making-WCF-Service-Calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on how to read cookies from response.

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var domain = "http://yourServiceURL.com";
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(domain).Result;

Uri uri = new Uri(domain);
IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
var cookieWithId =  responseCookies.Single(o => o.Name == "SessionId");
```

Comment: I tried this but no cookie is received. Although I can see cookie is returned when I make a request from a REST client i.e. PostMan. Also tried the code in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx but same result :(

Comment: I have checked in fiddler that there is a cookie in response but my application cannot see it

Comment: @Haris put a breakpoint on line `Uri uri = new Uri(domain);` then inspect `response2` in watch window in Visual Studio, my guess is that domain name or cookie name are incorrect.

Comment: thanks your code was right. I have never used httpclient class so having trouble reading the response from the service.